# how to fix import excel file in php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, import, reader

i have problem with import data excel in php use excel_reader.

this is error view

[pict error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We2Eo.png)

this is my code :

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/excel/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);                

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        echo'<script>alert("Upload gagal. Perhatikan ekstensi file. Ekstensi harus xls. Apabila ekstensi sudah xls namun gagal, lengkapi data dalam file xls.");</script>';
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('upload_excel_cust');
        $this->load->view('include/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('error' => false);
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();


        $this->load->library('Excel_reader');
        $this->excel_reader->setOutputEncoding('230787');

        $file =  $upload_data['full_path'];
        $this->excel_reader->read($file);
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        // Sheet 1
        $data = $this->excel_reader->sheets[0] ;
                    $dataexcel = Array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) {

                        if($data['cells'][$i][1] == '') break;
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['tgl'] = $data['cells'][$i][2];
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['nama_tempat'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
```

i've been read the problem cause excel_reader file not support in php 7,
how i can fix it?

thankyou...

[solved]

this problem solved, i just need change name function same with name class in to (__construct)

thankyou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to read excel file you can read this post [read excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528538/php-codeigniter-file-doesnt-get-uploaded-fast-enough-and-it-continues-the-proc/37528956#37528956)

Verify that your PHPExcel folderPHPExcel file are in your third_party folder, then in your application/library folder you need to create a Excel.php with

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel.php";

class Excel extends PHPExcel {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: cant fix sir, the result same.. "Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Excel_reader has a deprecated constructor"

Comment: Hi, first, [download PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187) the latest version or 1.8.0v, then unzip it, then in Clasess/* copy all into application/third_party folder, then in applicaton/libraries create a file with the code i give you above, then in your controller only call like the link i give you in the first comment